# Trouble fetching multiple data which one is dependent to other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

I have two async function for fetching data.

As you can see, second `fetchURL` is depending on first function's state. Since second one need to wait first one, I tried get data when `openseaCollection != null` but didn't work.

`fetchStats` function is working, but after clicking the button two times. What can I do here?

```
  const fetchOpenSeaData = async () => {
    if (collection.length) {
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
      };
      const fetchURL = `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contract/${collection}`;
      const nfts = await fetch(fetchURL, requestOptions).then((data) =>
        data.json()
      );
      if (nfts) {
        console.log("Collection Info", nfts);
        setOpenseaCollection(nfts);
      }
    }
  };

  const fetchStats = async () => {
    if (openseaCollection != null) {
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
      };
      const fetchURL = `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${openseaCollection?.collection?.slug}/stats`;
      const nfts = await fetch(fetchURL, requestOptions).then((data) =>
        data.json()
      );
      if (nfts) {
        console.log("Collection Stats", nfts);
        setStats(nfts);
      }
    }
  }; 

<button
          onClick={() => {
            if (fetchForCollection) { // fetchForCollection is just a state of checkbox and everything's fine.
              fetchNFTsForCollection();
              fetchOpenSeaData();
              fetchStats();
            } else fetchNFTs();
          }}
        >
          Go!
        </button>
```

Edit:
Here my all states.

```
  const [collection, setCollectionAddress] = useState("");
  const [NFTs, setNFTs] = useState([]);
  const [openseaCollection, setOpenseaCollection] = useState([]);
  const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);
  const [fetchForCollection, setFetchForCollection] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Could you share how you defined your states? `collection`, `openseaCollection`, `fetchForCollection`, etc.?

Comment: Hi, Emiel. I added my states. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's all async, you run all of them it will be race condition of course.

You have to do await on onClick

```
onClick={async () => {
            if (fetchForCollection) { // fetchForCollection is just a state of checkbox and everything's fine.
              await fetchNFTsForCollection();
              await fetchOpenSeaData();
              await fetchStats();
            } else fetchNFTs();
          }}
```

Comment: sorry, but still getting on second time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to utilize your states more with `useEffect`. When you click the button set the `fetchForCollection` state to `true`.

This state change should trigger the first `fetchNFTsForCollection` function which updates the `collection` state. That triggers the `fetchOpenSeaData` function that updates `openseaCollection` state which calls the `fetchStats` function.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [collection, setCollectionAddress] = useState("");
  const [NFTs, setNFTs] = useState([]);
  const [openseaCollection, setOpenseaCollection] = useState([]);
  const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);
  const [fetchForCollection, setFetchForCollection] = useState(false);

  const fetchNFTsForCollection = () => {
    const fetchURL = `...`;
    return fetch(fetchURL).then((response) => response.json());
  };

  const fetchOpenSeaData = useCallback(() => {
    const fetchURL = `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contract/${collection}`;
    return fetch(fetchURL).then((response) => response.json());
  }, [collection]);

  const fetchStats = useCallback(() => {
    const fetchURL = `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${openseaCollection?.collection?.slug}/stats`;
    return fetch(fetchURL).then((response) => response.json());
  }, [openseaCollection]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fetchForCollection === true) {
      fetchNFTsForCollection()
        .then((collection) => {
          setCollectionAddress(collection);
          setFetchForCollection(false);
        });
    }
  }, [fetchForCollection, setFetchForCollection, setCollectionAddress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (collection.length) {
      fetchOpenSeaData()
        .then(nfts => {
          if (nfts) {
            console.log("Collection Info", nfts);
            setOpenseaCollection(nfts);
          }
        });
    }
  }, [collection, setOpenseaCollection]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (openseaCollection !== null) {
      fetchStats()
        .then(nfts => {
          if (nfts) {
            console.log("Collection Stats", nfts);
            setStats(nfts);
          }
        });
    }
  }, [openseaCollection, setStats]);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setFetchForCollection(true);
      }}
    >
      Go!
    </button>
  );
};
```